# How to fetch filtering options from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in elasticsearch. I want to generate filter options on multiple fields to be shown on UI.
I have data of clothes in elasticsearch, with properties `"Brand", "Color", "Price"` in elasticsearch.
I want to fetch from elasticsearch List of brands, colors and price ranges as applicable.
Also, I want the list to be modified based on filter selection, for instance, if the user selected `"nike"` in Brand, then colors which are not present in `"nike"` should not be fetched.

My ES Mapping

```
{
    "mappings":{
        "products": {
            "properties": { 
              "title": { "type": "text"}, 
              "description": { "type": "text"}, 
              "productCode": { "type": "keyword"}, 
              "brand" : {"type":"keyword","fields": {"raw": {"type":  "text"}}}, 
              "color" : {"type":"keyword","fields": {"raw": {"type":  "text"}}}, 
              "category" : {"type":"keyword","fields": {"raw": {"type":  "text"}}}, 
              "price" : {"type":"double"}, 
              "imageLink" : {"type":"keyword"}
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also open to changing my ES mapping, as I am building it from scratch.

Comment: Please post sample of your data in elasticsearch. Based on how your data is stored this can be achievable.

Comment: @ben5556 I have added My ES mapping in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are called [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) in ES. I would start with [`Terms Aggregations`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) which is a type of bucket aggregation.

A quick example of an aggregation for `"brand"` would be something like this:

```
GET <index_name>/products/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "brands" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "brand" }
        }
    }
}
```